# Backup software for backing up specific files only

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, backup

I need some backup software for just backing up files of a particular type or a smart folder. In this case I need to backup all my video. Is there a free backup software available that will accomplish this for me?

Comment: want a sort of incremental backup (like TimeMachine), or only a simple copy of current files?

Comment: Just simple copy of files of specific type. The files will be access by both Windows and Mac OS's

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac has batteries already included. The only drawback (for some people) than it is command line (Terminal.app) solution.

The following shell script can do the job

```
case $# in
    (2) SRC="$1"; DEST="$2";;
    (*) echo "Usage: $0 source destination"; exit 1;;
esac

cd "$SRC" || exit 2
find . -type f -print0 | grep -ziv 'cpan' | grep -ziE '.(avi|mov|mp4)$' | rsync -n -av0 --files-from=- ./ "$DEST"
```

Save it into some file (e.g. mybackup.sh) and run from the terminal: sh ./mybackup.sh /path/to/the/source /path/to/the/dest, e.g.:

```
sh ./mybackup.sh ~/Downloads /Volumes/your_usb_hdd_name/path
```

Run the scipt and if you satisfiled with the result (will print out what will backing up), remove the '-n'. (The '-n' mean dry run)

rsync can do network backup to, or is possible emulate the TimeMachne functionality too, (incremental backup), etc - rsync is extremely powerful.

If you interested, can learn more with `man rsync` from the Terminal.

Ps:
Or, it is not enough simply select in finder's search "All Movies" and simple drag&drop to result into the destination?

Comment: Thanks, my videos are scattered all across my iMac, I geuss I should move them into one location first ? or can script be amended to find all vidoes?

Comment: The script looks at all directories under the SRV directory

Comment: The above script find **all** avi, mov, and mp4 videos (defined by file extension) which are anywhere in the "source_tree". Will copy them into "dest". Can you define what extensions want? Or i should modify the script find really all video files everywhere on your mac, but taht type of script will run really LONG (several 10 minutes).

Comment: analysing files regardless their extension is not the best idea. so would be helfull, if you can provide a list of extensions - what want backing up. And really want search your WHOLE mac? not only your HOME?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.crashplan.com/ is free for offline usage and can backup folders to an external drive or over LAN. Maybe this helps!